Does there exist a **Field** $\mathbb{F}$ with a valuation generating the Group $\mathbf{No}$, and can it be $\mathbf{On}_2$?
I am wondering about the following:

Does there exist a Field $\mathbb{F}$ (possibly a proper class) such that there exists a valuation
$$\nu: \mathbb{F} \to \mathbf{No} \sqcup \{\infty\},$$
where $\mathbf{No}$ denotes the surreal numbers, and the image of $\nu$ generates the additive Group $\mathbf{No}$?

If such a Field $\mathbb{F}$ exists, can it be the Nimber Field $\mathbf{On}_2$ (the Field of nimbers, i.e., Conway’s Field of ordinal sums mod 2)?


A few key points to clarify:

The term "Field" here follows Conway's convention, referring to a domain that may be a proper class, rather than a set-based field.
The valuation $\nu$ can take values in $\mathbf{No} \sqcup \{\infty\}$, where $\infty$ plays the usual role of valuation infinity.
By "the image generates the Group $\mathbf{No}$," I mean that the additive Group generated by $\nu(\mathbb{F} \setminus \{0\})$ should be the entire Group $\mathbf{No}$.

I suspect that $\mathbf{On}_2$ might not be sufficient to generate the entire Group $\mathbf{No}$, but I am curious whether a proper class Field with this property can exist, and whether $\mathbf{On}_2$ can serve as such a Field.

Is there a reason you use the capitalized "Field"?

"Field (i.e., a field whose
domain is a proper Class)—in general we shall capitalise the initial letter of
any “big” concept, on the grounds that proper Classes, like proper names,
deserve capital letters. So, for instance, the word Group will mean any group
whose domain is a proper class." - On Numbers And Games, Conway.
